# $<LINK_ONLY:MKL::MKL> conflicts with --start-group/--end-group

Tags: cmake

My CMakeLists structure as follows: (libA,libB,target are in differnet directories)

```
target_link_libraries(libA $<LINK_ONLY:MKL::MKL>)
target_link_libraries(libB --start-group lib1...libn --end-group)
target_link_libraries(target libA libB)
```

I came across "undefined reference to ..." when building target, then I checked `link.txt`, and find that there was something wrong generating correct MKL libraries link options, I expexted to see

```
Wl,--start-group libmkl_core.a ... Wl,--end-group
```

however, the wrong content is

```
libmkl_core.a Wl,--start-group Wl,--end-group
```

My CMake version is 3.24

Things come back to normal after I replace `--start-group lib1...libn --end-group` with `$<LINK_GROUP:RESCAN`
Also, `$<LINK_ONLY:MKL::MKL>` can work well when target only links libA, as follows:

```
target_link_libraries(libA $<LINK_ONLY:MKL::MKL>)
target_link_libraries(target libA libB)
```

Comment: The call to `target_link_libraries(target libA libB)` guarantees only that `libA` will be passed to the linker before the `libB`. It doesn't guarantee that dependent libraries of `libA` will be passed to the linker before dependent libraries of `libB`. And using `--start-group`/`--end-group` directly in the `target_link_libraries` is wrong: CMake by itself handles those parameters.